# Submit a form with A tag and value

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I know that by using:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.formName.submit();">
```

I can submit a form, but what if I need to submit it with a value?

Say I have this form

```
<form name="f1" id="f1" role="form">
<input type="radio" name="myesno" value="yes" id="myesno1"> Yes
<input type="radio" name="myesno" value="no" id="myesno2"> No
</form>
```

So neither are selected and neither are required, this form is show at the top of the page, and at the bottom has to be another form for the same purpose, so, as you can see is kind of redundant to have 2 forms for the same thing specially if they are in the same page...
So my idea is to use < A > tags to submit this form, but the thing is how do I submit it with a value?

```
<a href="#" > Yes </a> | <a href="#" > No </a>
```

So how do I do that?

Comment: Ideally a form with radio buttons and a submit button (for a simple yes/no form) should be used. It's logical is easy to implement...

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<form name="f1" id="f1" role="form">
<input type="hidden" name="selected_option" id="selected_option" value="" />
<a class="opt_button" data-value="yes" href="#" > Yes </a> | <a data-value="no" class="opt_button" href="#" > No </a>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.opt_button').on('click', function() {
        $('#selected_option').val($(this).attr('data-value'));
        $('#f1').submit();
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
if ($_POST['selected_option'] == 'yes') {
    echo "Yes was selected";
} elseif ($_POST['selected_option'] == 'no') {
    echo "No was selected";
} else {
    echo "Neither option was selected";
}
```

Comment: I like the Java, but for some reason is not submitting the form, if I do a little "test" with an alert(); is works, but not the submit part, could it be because I'm using iCheck library?

Answer (score 0):

override the onclick to change a value in a hidden input (untested) assuming your using jQuery

```
<input type="hidden" id='hiddenid' value="yes" name="Parametername">

<a href="#" id="submit";">

<script>
$(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function() {

    $('#formid').submit();
       // insertlogic
       $('#hiddenid').val('somevalue')
    });
});
</script>
```